# Xcode executable link dependencies issue

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic-linking

When I add library (libboost_thread.dylib) to my executable by dragging it from `/opt/local/lib` it's added correctly - running `otool -L` on executable file shows full path to libboost_thread.dylib (i.e. `/opt/local/lib/libboost_thread.dylib`).

If I have separate boost installation which places libraries into `<boost_dir>/stage/lib` and drag this library from there, `otool -L` on executable shows just "libboost_thread.dylib" without fully qualifying path. This results in runtime error `"Library not loaded: libboost_thread.dylib"`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know why XCode does this, but it's fixable using `install_name_tool` (there's a question somewhere on here about this). Incidentally, it's _not_ correct for it to show `/opt/local/lib/libboost_thread.dylib` in your executable, assuming you want your program to run on systems that don't have Boost installed through MacPorts. The correct path would have something like `@rpath`, `@loader_path`, or `@executable_path` at the start.

Comment: thanks, @celticminstrel. I'm aware of this tool and these helpful variables. Though, I'd like to know why does it happen.